# I am working with TypeScript and React and I need to detect a click for a dynamically created element in my document

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I need to detect a click for the `<p>` tag with the `id = "rightDisplayBtn"`. I tried attaching a onclick function or an event listener but none of them worked.

```
function addDetails() {
    hideModal();
    addBookDiv.innerHTML = '';
    for (var n in addressBook) {
        var str = '<div id="displayButton">';
        str += '<p class="contactdisp main-name" id="rightDisplayBtn' + addressBook[n].srno + '" style="font-size: 40px;font-family:"Candara"; text-decoration: none;" onclick="getName(this.id)">' + addressBook[n].name + '</p>';
        str += '<p class="contactdisp border-style"  style="font-family: "sans-serif";">' + addressBook[n].mail + '</p>';
        str += '<p class="contactdisp border-style borderbottom" style="font-family: "sans-serif";">+91 ' + addressBook[n].mobile + '</p></div>';
        addBookDiv.innerHTML += str;
        nameFieldDef();
        mailFieldDef();
        mobileFieldDef();
        clearForm();
        hideWatermark();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use proper react components rather than concatenating strings. Then you can say (e.g.)                `<div ... onClick={this.handleClick}/>`. Make sure you bind your function:         `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`

Comment: I really wish I understood what you said right there but I just started yesterday. I'll look up what you said :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by adding an `onClick()` on your element. You will need a way to run through your array, in React the common way to accomplish this is by using `Array.prototype.map()` ([map](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)).

You can just map through the array and provide the needed elements instead of doing `element.innerHTML`...

```js
import React, { MouseEvent } from "react";

// provide an interface for setting an address 
interface AddressInterface {
  id: number;
  street: string;
}

export default function App() {

  // some dummy data
  const addressBook: AddressInterface[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      street: "St1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      street: "St2"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      street: "St3"
    }
  ];

  // click handler with TS typing for event
  const handleClick = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>, id: number) => {
    console.log(id); // do something with result
  };

  // map the addresses and return elements
  const mappedAddresses = addressBook.map((a, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i} onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, a.id)}>
        <p>
          {a.street} (id:{a.id})
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return { mappedAddresses };
}
```

Since you are using TypeScript, I added an interface for your addresses (feel free to change this however you like).

Comment: Would `ReactDOM.render(mappedAddresses, document.getElementById("xyz"))` Render the elements?

Comment: I think the way you should approach this is by making a new component (eg Addresses.tsx), putting this code inside the component, and calling the component in App.tsx or index.tsx (or where your `ReactDOM.render` code is, like this: <Addresses />)

Comment: Normally, the component should render correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a normal onClick Listener ([Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html))

But the greater Problem is your string concatenation.

You should always use React components.

I tried to rewrite your code and use React Components.

But please dont expect that it works (it needs your variables you provided):

```js
let addBookDiv = <div></div> // or use <></>

function addDetails() {
    hideModal();
    addBookDiv = (
        <div>
            <div>
                <div id="displayButton">
                    <p class="contactdisp main-name" id={"rightDisplayBtn"+ {addressBook[n].srno}}
                       style="font-size: 40px;font-family: Candara; text-decoration: none;"
                       onclick={getName(this.id)}>{addressBook[n].name}</p>
                    <p class="contactdisp border-style" style="font-family:  sans-serif;">{addressBook[n].mail}</p>
                    <p class="contactdisp border-style borderbottom" style="font-family: sans-serif;">
                        {+91 + addressBook[n].mobile}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
    nameFieldDef();
    mailFieldDef();
    mobileFieldDef();
    clearForm();
    hideWatermark();

}

function render() {
    return (
        {addBookDiv}
    )
}
```

You can also use a Touchable Component ([Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-touches#touchables)) to make an "invisible Button"

But a simple onClick Listener should already work.

Comment: @varung1303 No problem :) It would be nice if you would mark this question as solved :)

Comment: I will give you a vote for effort! Good answer, consider giving me some feedback also :)